# Fail to Write to Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Faced some difficulties when writing data to Firebase, i basically just have a simple button when pressed, data will be written to database. Don't know whats the issue, would appreciate any help. thanks in advance :)

```
    firebaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");
            myRef.setValue("Successful");

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: The whole code gets executed because the Toast message will appear when button is pressed. However no data is uploaded to Firebase, I suppose based on the code , “Successful” will be uploaded each time button is submitted

Comment: Have you tried to use something like this? `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").setValue("Successful");`

Comment: show the structure of your database

Comment: @Ali my database has 1 child, Users that’s all

Comment: What about the database rules. Check that.

Comment: @Jey.L Have you tried my above line of code?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm out now will try again when i get back to you! Thanks for your input

Comment: Also check your logcat for any security warnings/errors.

Comment: update firebase database rules.
database.getReference("Users",, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to connect firebase with android studio.

```
Tools -> Firebase -> Realtime Database -> Connect
```

Also change the rules of your realtime database so that you are allowed to write on your database.

```
For this go your firebase console. Open your realtime database and go to rules section. In that section make sure the write settings are set to true.
```

Hope this works. If it doesn't see to logcat for errors.